# Class accepting template or template template params

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Is there any way to have a class which accepts both normal template params or template template params?

i.e. something that would work equally well like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct TMP;
```

or this:

```
template <template <typename> typename T>
struct TMP;
```

**tl;dr** to avoid reptition. But for a full explanation, see below:

When doing Template Meta-Programming, one sometimes needs various helper structs (like to merge a list of types into one) and you can write such a utility for both template params and template template params etc, but they are virtually identical apart from a few characters. So I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate the redundancy.

Example:

Here is some TMP to merge two lists of normal template params (i.e. two tuples)

```
// merge two tuples types into one
template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
struct tuple_merge;

template <typename... LHS_Params, typename... RHS_Params>
struct tuple_merge<std::tuple<LHS_Params...>,
                   std::tuple<RHS_Params...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<LHS_Params..., RHS_Params...>;
};
```

But sometimes you might be working with template template params, so you might do the same thing for them like so:

```
// the container of template template params
template <template <typename> typename...>
struct variadic_of_mono_template {};

// the merger of them
template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
struct mono_template_merge;

template <template <typename> typename... LHS_Params,
          template <typename> typename... RHS_Params>
struct mono_template_merge<variadic_of_mono_template<LHS_Params...>,
                           variadic_of_mono_template<RHS_Params...>> {
  using type =
      variadic_of_mono_template<LHS_Params..., RHS_Params...>;
};
```

As you can see they are virtually identical. They only differ in whether they say a param is `typename` or `template <typename> typename`. And if there are many TMP utilities like this, the repetition can get quite extensive.

Any way to avoid the repetition?

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/uuNo_n)

Comment: You can wrap a template template within another template and pass it as a type (See `integral_constant` which is the same concept, but for values): `template_oftypes<TMP>` and pass it to your normal merger meta function. When you need to access the template, you can unwrap it using a using declaration inside, or partial specialization matching. For your second TMP, you can create `template_oftemplates<TMP>`. At some level deep down, unfortunately you have to make this distunction. Unless C++17 or C++20 introduced some magic cool feature here that I don't know about, but I guess not!